# Need to compile and run Java & spring boot projects in eclipse theia IDE

Tags: java, docker, visual-studio-code, eclipse-che, theia

I am new to eclipse theia IDE.I created theia as docker image. I ran docker image with java project workspace.

I am not able to compile and run Java projects. My doubt is I added Java related vs code plugins mentioned in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

But still my java or spring boot projects are not able to compile & run.

My question is Eventhough we already installed vscode java extentions and still we need to install jdk, maven manually or not.

Any suggestions or samples are much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the extensions only combine the 'jdk' or 'maven' and so on with the VSCode, so you need to install them manually.

'Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat' extension has settings of 'java.home', you can refer to [this](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#setting-the-jdk) page for more information.

'Maven for Java' extension has settings of 'maven.executable.path', you can refer to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-maven#settings) page for more information.